# Cannot load my YOLOv3 model into readNetFromDarknet

Tags: python, opencv, yolo

So I have trained a YOLOv3 model and want to test the accuracy of the model. I am trying to load the model by using the command 'cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet'. Every time I try I receive the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Philip\PycharmProjects\Scriptie\venv\tester.py", line 9, in <module>
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet(modelConfiguration, modelWeights)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\darknet\darknet_io.cpp:660: error: (-215:Assertion failed) separator_index < line.size() in function 'cv::dnn::darknet::ReadDarknetFromCfgStream'
```

**The python code that I am using is shown below:**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
classes = ['TEETH']

modelConfiguration = r"C:\Users\Philip\PycharmProjects\Scriptie\venv\yolov3_custom.cfg"
modelWeights = r"C:\Users\Philip\PycharmProjects\Scriptie\venv\yolov3_custom_2000.weights"

net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet(modelConfiguration, modelWeights)
```

I have tried changing the paths to absolute paths but it didn't work, anyone that can help me with this?

Comment: opencv version?

Comment: The version of openv that I am using is: 4.5.5

Comment: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/10160#issuecomment-597308170

Comment: the error states, that your cfg file is broken. can you add the 1st 20 lines or so here ?

Comment: How did you train the dnn? Which framework? Which OS?

Comment: it's trying to parse `key=value` pairs, and could not find a seperating `=` [see here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/50e8ad285b6fcf388c4283b2c433aac099a6562c/modules/dnn/src/darknet/darknet_io.cpp#L659-L660)

Comment: Why not try this [link]https://valueml.com/object-detection-from-a-video-with-yolov3-in-python/   Look in line 3 and 4.